# Adding numbers to graphs

Tags: python, pandas, graph

I have created a pretty lollipop graph with countries on my y-axis and values on the x.

```
Data = {'Country': ['UK','Ireland', 'South Africa','Botswana','Italy','Greece'], 
        'Assessment': [170,170, 170, 65,64,53]}

df= pd.DataFrame(data = data)

ordered_fa = df.sort_values(by='Assessment')

my_range=range(1,len(df.index)+1)

a4_dims = (10, 12)
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=a4_dims)
sns.despine(offset=50)

plt.hlines(y=my_range, xmin=0, xmax=ordered_fa['Assessment'], color='skyblue')
plt.plot(ordered_fa['Assessment'], my_range, "o")

# Add titles and axis names
plt.yticks(my_range, ordered_fa['Country'])
plt.title("Assessments per month (2018)", loc='left')
```

I would like to add a numeric label at the end of each "o" reporting the number.

How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Please use `ax.text(x, y, 'str')`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd


Data = {'Country': ['UK','Ireland', 'South Africa','Botswana','Italy','Greece'], 
        'Assessment': [170,170, 170, 65,64,53]}

df= pd.DataFrame(data = Data)

ordered_fa = df.sort_values(by='Assessment')

my_range=range(1,len(df.index)+1)

a4_dims = (10, 12)
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=a4_dims)
# sns.despine(offset=50)

plt.hlines(y=my_range, xmin=0, xmax=ordered_fa['Assessment'], color='skyblue')
plt.plot(ordered_fa['Assessment'], my_range, "o")

# Add titles and axis names
plt.yticks(my_range, ordered_fa['Country'])
plt.title("Assessments per month (2018)", loc='left')

for i in my_range:
        x = 7 - i
        y = Data['Assessment'][i-1]
        ax.text(y + 2,x,str(y))



plt.show()
```